# Adding API options to initialization script?

Tags: javascript, initialization

I'd like to add the following API options to my fancybox initialization script, following an advice given by someone in this forum ([Saving images in Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312998/saving-images-in-fancybox)).  Adding these options are said to increase the margins on the sides when fancybox images are opened.

But, the problem is I don't know how/where to add.

This is my initialization script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $(".fancybox").fancybox(); });
```

And this is the API options suggested:

```
margin : [20, 60, 20, 60]
```

Can anybody help me add the API into the script?  (And What's API? excuse my ignorance)

Comment: Before opening a question, close your last one. (select an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as options inside the `fancybox` function

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
     margin: [20, 60, 20, 60]
   });

http://fancybox.net/howto

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried but the margins remain the same.  Did I do something wrong?